# Function to change the levels of a factor variable in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, levels

I have a factored variable `Clic_1` in a data frame `oldata`. I want to write a function that will change the value of the factored variables.

```
head(oldata$CliC_1)
[1] 4 1 5 3 5 5
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5
```

I tried this function but it is giving NA

```
try<- function (data,var){
    for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
            if (var[i]== "1"){
                    var[i]<- "Good"
            } else {var[i]<- "Bad"}        
    }
    return (var)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a custom function or `relevel`. Just use `ifelse`:

```
factor(ifelse(oldata$CliC_1==1, 'Good', 'Bad'))
# Bad  Good Bad  Bad  Bad  Bad
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be

```
factor(oldata$CliC_1 != 1, labels = c('Good', 'Bad'))
# [1] Bad  Good Bad  Bad  Bad  Bad 
# Levels: Good Bad
```

Comment: Thank you s much. But, I also want to understand what was my mistake in that function? Do you have any clue? And also If I have more than two levels e.g. "good', "moderate", "bad"

Comment: Your function works fine for me. Just wrap it into `factor` as in `return (factor(var))` and call some other name because `try` is already existing function in R. Other than that, your function isn't vectorized, so it is better to use other methods. If you need other levels it will get more complicated than just a simple Boolean condition.